# Notepad++ Find File Name

Tags: notepad++

In Notepad++ I need to open files sometimes, existing in different folders, which takes time to go to the folder, and search the file through Light Explorer.

Is there any feature or plug-in of Notepad++, which will let me open the files directly. For suppose, if I need to open a file with the name notepad.php, all I need to do is to write notepad or note, and it finds me the similar filenames starting with what I've queried.

Thanks

Comment: i need this in notepad++ plz.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of any plugins, but why not just write a batch file that will open them for you in Notepad++?

For example, if you need all of the files in a directory structure named "notepad.php" opened in Notepad++ create a batch file like so:

```
for %%i in ("dir /b /s" notepad.php) do %programfiles%\Notepad++\notepad++.exe %%i
```

This will open all of the files called notepad.php within the directory structure it is run in.