# Search file names and contents on Windows using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, winapi, pywin32

[image: Always search files and contents]

The idea is to **search files and its contents** via Windows Search.
I have turned on `Always search files and contents` in `Change folder and search options` on Windows. Is it possible to search files and contents with **python** and **win32api**, while option is enabled in settings as shown above ?

Can anyone show me some examples if possible how to achieve this goal ?
I do not want to search files with python and its modules to parse data from there, just want to use itself Windows to search files.

Thanks.

Comment: You could try to use [Notepad++](https://github.com/MattBDev/notepad-plus-plus/blob/master/README.md) to search file names and contents on Windows. For more details, Isuggest you could refer to the threads:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9093575/notepad-find-file-name
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12215896/searching-multiple-files-for-multiple-words/17874867

Comment: [Windows Search](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/search/windows-search) has a [programming interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/search/-search-developers-guide-entry-page).